# How to use Windows and Form authentication in a single project for internal and external users for .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We want to figure it out, when the user is using the application within the network/domain then the application will auto-authenticate and redirect to the dashboard otherwise if the user is using the application from an outside domain application will auto-redirect to the application's login page

We've created an application and after deployment on the IIS server, we're able to authenticate with windows authentication either forms authentication

Comment: First, don't target .NET Core 3.1 because it reaches End of Life in 3 weeks. EOL means no patches or fixes at all, even for critical security issues. Library authors will quickly drop support for 3.1 too. The current Long Term Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024.

Comment: Could you please, share more details how its been determided that  `within the network/domain` and `outside domain application`. In addition, could you please share relevant `code snippet` for this so that it can be checked.